# how to remove controller subfolder from the url in codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3

http://localhost/ccs/user/my-account/dashboard

I want to remove the sub folder user from url in **codeigniter 3**

Comment: learn how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using codeigniter URL ROUTING .
Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file.
e.g

$route['product/:num'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';

for more detail visit given link https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html